# How to catch different exceptions of the same type?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I find myself in a situation similar to the code below.

I have a try block, and I am testing the values of two different variables. If one of them is incorrect I would like to raise an exception a ValueError exception, but I would like to handle them differently depending on which one occurs.

```
fingers = 8
thumbs = 3

try:
    if fingers == 8:
        print("8 Is the usual amount of fingers")
    else:
        raise ValueError("That's a strange amount of fingers to have")

    if thumbs ==  2:
        print("You have the usual amount of thumbs")
    else:
        raise ValueError("That's a strange amount of thumbs to have")

except ValueError as e1:
    print("You had the wrong amount of fingers - let me perform surgery and fix that for you")
    fingers = 8

except ValueError as e2:
    print("You had the wrong amount of thumbs - let me perform surgery and fix that for you")
    thumbs = 2
```

Obviously as it's written now, this error gets incorrectly caught as the finger one. Is there a way to catch them seperately somehow while still throwing a value error exception? Or do I need to create two seperate custom exception classes to deal with a situation like this?

Comment: You could catch a single `ValueError`, and then look at `e1.args` to see if it's the fingers message or the thumbs message.  But in this case I think it would be better to have separate exceptions.

Comment: `if 'fingers' in str(e1):...`

Comment: You could derive two different `ValueError` subclasses, one for each case, which would allow you to differentiate them. It's very easy: i.e. `class WrongFingers(ValueError): pass`.

Answer (score 6):

You could pass arbitrary amount of arguments to a `ValueError`, so you can distinguish your errors if you want:

```py
fingers = 8
thumbs = 3

try:
    if fingers == 8:
        print("8 Is the usual amount of fingers")
    else:
        raise ValueError("That's a strange amount of fingers to have", "fingers")

    if thumbs == 2:
        print("You have the usual amount of thumbs")
    else:
        raise ValueError("That's a strange amount of thumbs to havet", "thumbs")

except ValueError as err:
    if err.args[1] == "fingers":
        print(
            "You had the wrong amount of fingers - let me perform surgery and fix that for you"
        )
        fingers = 8

    if err.args[1] == "thumbs":
        print(
            "You had the wrong amount of thumbs - let me perform surgery and fix that for you"
        )
        thumbs = 2
```

As you can see I've passed `"fingers"` and `"thumbs"` as a second argument to the respective errors, and then later using the error argument list I could find out which one of them was raised.

Also let me note that although it works, I don't see any particular reason not to go for your custom exception classes, they make your code easier to read and more reasonable:

```py
fingers = 8
thumbs = 2


class FingersValueError(ValueError):
    pass


class ThumbsValueError(ValueError):
    pass


try:
    if fingers == 8:
        print("8 Is the usual amount of fingers")
    else:
        raise FingersValueError("That's a strange amount of fingers to have", "fingers")

    if thumbs == 2:
        print("You have the usual amount of thumbs")
    else:
        raise ThumbsValueError("That's a strange amount of thumbs to havet", "thumbs")

except FingersValueError:

    print(
        "You had the wrong amount of fingers - let me perform surgery and fix that for you"
    )
    fingers = 8

except ThumbsValueError:
    print(
        "You had the wrong amount of thumbs - let me perform surgery and fix that for you"
    )
    thumbs = 2
```

And since the custom errors are derived from `ValueError` you can also catch them in a single `except` block and then check their type:

```py
except ValueError as err:

    if isinstance(err, FingersValueError):
        print(
            "You had the wrong amount of fingers - let me perform surgery and fix that for you"
        )
        fingers = 8

    if isinstance(err, ThumbsValueError):
        print(
            "You had the wrong amount of thumbs - let me perform surgery and fix that for you"
        )
        thumbs = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this slight modification.

```
fingers = 8

thumbs = 3

if fingers == 8:
    print("8 Is the usual amount of fingers")
else:
    print("You had the wrong amount of fingers - let me perform surgery and fix that for you")
    fingers = 8
        
if thumbs ==  2:
    print("You have the usual amount of thumbs")
else:
    print("You had the wrong amount of thumbs - let me perform surgery and fix that for you")
    thumbs = 2
```

If that does not work for you, use two separate try except statements.

Then, if that **still** does not work, create a child classes of the exception, and look for the child classes.